# create Python package and import modules

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I'm trying to write my first Python package, and almost all my modules will need to use NumPy. Should I write `import numpy` in every single module or is there some place in the package I can just import it once so every module can use it? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's much cost to writing `import numpy` at the top of each file.

Comment: @askewchan, Thanks, I just want to make sure there's no redundancy. I don't want to import the same thing over and over again.

Comment: I still believe that the cost, including redundancy of reimporting, is lower than the lack of readability you might introduce with something more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just import it everywhere it's needed.

*Don't* get too clever with writing functions that import everything for you or metamodules that import things and from which you `import *`; all of that only serves to make your code hard to read and is just another place for bugs to happen.